# Threading in python, need help to make the program wait based on a condition on another function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying something in python using threading. This is my first time to use threads. So any help would be appreciated.

So here is the thing. I am starting 10 threads to do something in another function. But if some condition is met in the other function, I should be able to call join() on all these threads. So I need to find a way to pass the thread objects to the other function. Can someone please help me to find a way for this.

```
def db_routine():
#global t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t0
connection = pymysql.connect(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='franchisedb')
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "select number, url, address, flag from `colleges_com`"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        #connection.commit()
        row=cursor.fetchone()
        while row is not None:
            if row[3] == 1:
                print("Item already processed.")
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                continue
            if row[2] != None:
                print("Address exists for the entry number: " + str(row[0]))
                row = cursor.fetchone()
            else:
                print("Adding address for the entry number: " + str(row[0]))
                time.sleep(.5)
                if row[0]%10 == 1:
                    t1 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t1.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 2:
                    t2 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t2.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 3:
                    t3 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t3.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 4:
                    t4 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t4.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 5:
                    t5 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t5.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 6:
                    t6 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t6.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 7:
                    t7 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t7.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 8:
                    t8 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t8.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 9:
                    t9 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t9.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
                elif row[0]%10 == 0:
                    t0 = threading.Thread(target=goto_url, args = (row[0], row[1]))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    t0.start()
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
finally:
    connection.close()
    cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

threads can be exited by returning from targeted function using a global variable master_wish does the trick in following example:

```
import threading
import time

master_wish = True # global variable


def kill_all_demons(demon):
    while True:
        print "killing %s\n" % demon
        if not master_wish:
            return

def van_helsing():
    print "Yes Master your wish is my command"
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=kill_all_demons, args=('Dracula',))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=kill_all_demons, args=('Wolf',))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()


def other_func():
    global master_wish
    master_wish = False
    print("good will prevail over evil")


van_helsing()
time.sleep(10)
other_func()
```